# How to configure Apache to serve HTTP version 2?

Tags: apache-2.4, http2

The configuration file of **Apache** already has the following:

```
LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
```

and...

```
<IfModule mod_http2.c>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfModule>
```

**HTTPS** is working too using certificate issued from **Let's Encrypt**.

However, when I try to request a resource say:

```
https://h2.example.com/index.html
```

Apache is still serving it with the protocol `http/1.1` and still not `h2`.

One thing I noticed was that the response for the resource just have the following header:

```
Server: Apache/2.4.41 () OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips
```

instead of the working ones with:

```
Server: Apache
Upgrade: h2,h2c
```

Did I miss something? How to configure Apache to serve HTTP version 2?

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton an error log says:

`[http2:warn] [pid 12345] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.` What did I miss?

Comment: You forgot to switch to the event MPM.